# How to create a graph chart without using Libraries (Matplotlib) in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, lib

I'm new to python. In an interview, the Hr ask me to create the Graph chart without using the Library like matplotlib. I tried a few ways but it does not work for me I've not cleared the interview as well. And people if you know how to make the graph like mentioned below without using a lib. Please share with me. any kind of suggestion is appreciatable.

[image: This image contains the Sample input and output]

Answer (score 2):

HHhhmmm.  Sounds like somebody is trying to check your ability to think outside the box and/or your knowledge of print formatting since it is never a good idea to reinvent the wheel on not use a better solution that already exists.  I generated some random numbers and 'plotted' a * using print statements.
I included a Matplotlib plot just to check how close it was.  You could add some code to calculate the derivative and change the symbol based on that.

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=range(50)
y= [random.randrange(0,5) for i in range(50)]

for yindex in range(5,-1,-1):
    for xindex in range(0,50,1):
        if y[xindex] == yindex:
            print("*", end='')
        else:
            print(" ", end='')
    print()
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFQ2R.png)